# .NET 5.0, Web API, custom model state response not working

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Migrated from .net core 3.1 to .net 5.0, added overwride data annoation modelstate, however it still outputting the standard response

Web api response

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-1c52b58af7ac14479da066f231bd7cc1-026c44e7e2148f4f-00",
  "errors": {
    "WebsiteUrl": [
      "Website url is invalid"
    ],
    "Phone": [
      "Phone number is invalid"
    ],
    "Country": [
      "Country code is invalid"
    ]
  }
}
```

startup.cs

```
        //Override modelstate
        services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = (context) =>
            {
               //custom api response goes here

                return new BadRequestObjectResult(apiResponse);
            };
        });
```

Comment: Can you show your apiResponse?I test with `return new BadRequestObjectResult(objecttype);`,and it can work.

Comment: Did you add url  phone, data annotations?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I just ran into what I thought was going to be a 10 minute fix but it doesn't even work.